# C++ ostream not creating a new file

Tags: c++, logging, ostream

This is the `WriteAppLog` code I used to create a log that app produces but I want to override the previous log OR create a new file with a new name every time.

Can someone help me modify?

```
void WriteAppLog (const std::string &s)
        {

        std::ofstream file ("AppLog.txt", std::ios::app);

        file << "[" << Helper::DateTime().GetDateTimeString () << "]" << "\n" << s << std::endl << "\n";
        file.close();
        }
```

Comment: If you’re using C++, please use the C++ tag.

Comment: If you don’t want the output appended, don’t use the append flag.  But I think you’ll find that you do want to append messages.  It is easier to see what was going on after the event if you have all the logged messages.

Comment: You don't need `file.close()`, the stream closes itself when going out of scope.

Comment: @skalet True, but closing the file manually is the only way to check for errors of the close operation.

Answer (score 2):

The mode flag `std::ios::app` indicates that the output should be appended to the file. You have to use `std::ios::out`:

```
std::ofstream file ("AppLog.txt", std::ios::out);
```

See [`std::ofstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/)

---

> OR create a new file with a new name

If you want to check if a file exists, then you can try to open the file for reading and check by [`std::ios::good()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/) if this succeeded:

```
bool exists( const std::string& fileName )
{
    std::ifstream infile(fileName.c_str())
    return infile.good();
}
```

Dependent on the result you can create a new file with a new name.

Comment: Using the `exist()` function would pose a [TOCTOU race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).